# Dynamic Programming, sum of all 3 subarrays after bitwise xor them

Tags: java, c#, dynamic-programming

I recently ran to a dynamic programming problem and I needed to solve it, so i couldn't figure it  out myself so I started looking for solutions. The problem is:

*There are N students in your class. The strength of each student is a small nonnegative integer.*

*You are
given these strengths in the int[] strength with N elements.
You are going to divide all students into three teams for the boat race "TrySail". Each student must be 
assigned to exactly one of the three teams. Teams cannot be empty.
Strangely enough, in this race the strength of a team is the bitwise xor of the strengths of its members. 
You want to maximize the sum of strengths of the three teams. Compute and return the largest possible 
sum of the teams' strengths.*

**Constraints:**

1) N will be between 3 and 50, inclusive.

2) strength will contain exactly N elements.

3)Each element of strength will be between 0 and 255, inclusive.

I found some solutions and specific this one. But i still don't know what happens here even when i debug it line per line. So if someone knows this problem or understands this and where and why he uses the variable sum and bitwise **xor** them (**^**) it would be really nice for some comments.

Here is the code:

```
public class TrySail
{
    public int get(int[] strength)
    {
        var dp = new bool[256, 256];
        dp[0, 0] = true;
        var sum = 0;
        foreach (var x in strength)
        {
            var next = new bool[256, 256];
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                {
                    if (!dp[i, j]) continue;
                    var rem = sum ^ i ^ j;
                    next[i ^ x, j] |= dp[i, j];
                    next[i, j ^ x] |= dp[i, j];
                    next[i, j] |= dp[i, j];
                }
            dp = next;
            sum ^= x;
        }
        var max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
            {
                if (!dp[i, j]) continue;
                var rem = sum ^ i ^ j;
                max = Math.Max(max, i + j + rem);
            }
        return max;
    }

}
```

An example:

```
{7,3,5,2}

Returns: 17

There are 6 ways to make 3 teams:

· {0},{1},{2,3}: sum of strengths is 7+3+(5 xor 2) = 17

· {0},{2},{1,3}: sum of strengths is 7+5+(3 xor 2) = 13

· {0},{3},{1,2}: sum of strengths is 7+2+(3 xor 5) = 15

· {1},{2},{0,3}: sum of strengths is 3+5+(7 xor 2) = 13

· {1},{3},{0,2}: sum of strengths is 3+2+(7 xor 5) = 7

· {2},{3},{0,1}: sum of strengths is 5+2+(7 xor 3) = 11

Therefore, the answer is 17.
```

The code is written in C#

Comment: I strongly disbelieve anyone's going to do your homework here.. Do you have any concrete question?

Comment: i only some comments why he uses that sum, for what exactly, this is just for analysing and commenting, or maybe can solve the problem with different algorithm